# Bash script to automatically email variable filename and corresponding modified datetime stamp

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In short, i am trying to find the duplicate files ( which have been downloaded from FTP site, it is another script file) and email the business about all the duplicate files and its corresponding modified dates.

The file `/path/test_mail.txt` contains one file name per line (two filenames in this case), ex.

```
abc.xlsx
def.xlsx
```

In the below code, i am trying to find the modified datetimestamp for the first filename and pipe it with the respective filename and send an email , similarly the loop runs for the second one.

This is using stat

```
for val in '/path/test_mail.txt'; do
        { stat path/$val | grep 'Modify: ' | cut -d' ' -f2,3,4 | awk -F"." '{print $1}' ; } |

        $val

done |


mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" abc@xyz.com
```

I also tried in another way using ls -ltr

```
for val in '/path/tj_mail.txt'; do
            { ls -ltr /path/$val | cut -d' ' -f6,7,8 | find $val / -path

$val

    done |


    mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" abc@xyz.com
```

i was expecting the email body should be approximately like

> Duplicate Filename -  xyz.xlsx      Uploaded time - 2020-02-17 11:18:10
>
> Duplicate Filename - abc.xlsx      Uploaded time -  2020-02-17 11:18:10

The below question is optional, but that would be great if you can help me!

Also i am using another script to find the duplicate filenames in the directory. it works perfectly fine. But i am wondering if i could fit in the same code above in 1 single script file, so that it would be crisp and easy!

```
{
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
dirname=/path
tempfile=myTempfileName
find $dirname -type f  > $tempfile
cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d|
while read fileName
do
 grep "$fileName" $tempfile
done
} | tee '/path/tj_var.txt' | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  | tee '/path/tj_var.txt' | sort -u | tee '/path/tj_mail.txt' | mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" abc@xyz.com
```

This is my actual code

> ```
> path = /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation
> printf "%s" "$(</marketsource/scripts/tj_mail.txt)" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
>    mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename")
>    printf 'Duplicate Filename - %s Uploaded time - %s\n' "$filename" "$mtime"
> done | mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" tipalli@allegisgroup.com
>
>  mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename" 2>/dev/null || echo "unknown (stat failed)")
> ```

this is the error!

> ./tj_mail1.ksh: line 1: path: command not found stat: cannot stat
>   `/path/AirTimeActs_2020-02-08.xlsx': No such file or directory

**Little more!!**

My aim to find for any duplicates files, if therent arent any duplicate files and find command is empty, then perform the if condition and perform 'mv' command and exit the script entirely, if they are duplicate files, then exit the if condition and pipe the duplicate files and perform the mail and date stamp operation.

```
    {
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
dirname=/marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation
tempfile=myTempfileName
find $dirname -type f  > $tempfile
cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d|
while read fileName
do
 grep "$fileName" $tempfile
done
}
if ["$fileName" == ""]; then
         mv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/*.xlsx /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/Archive

         mv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/*.csv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/Archive
        exit 1

fi | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_var.txt' | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_var.txt' | sort -u | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_mail.txt'



DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
printf "%s\n" "$(</marketsource/scripts/tj_mail.txt)" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/$filename")
   printf  'Duplicate Filename - %s Uploaded time - %s\n\n' "$filename" "$mtime"
done | mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" ti@allegisgroup.com
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to parse file information by using `grep` over `ls` or `stat`. For example you can get the modification date with `stat -c %y /path/to/file`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about what you want to achieve. Please explain what your non-working code is supposed to do.  Do you want to read the file `/path/test_mail.txt`? In this case show some example contents. Or is it an example for a file name pattern? Your `for` loops would run exactly once and call `stat path//path/test_mail.txt` or `ls -ltr /path//path/test_mail.txt` respectively. How do you detect duplicate file names? From duplicate lines in a file? Similar file names? Same file (base) names in different directories? ...

Comment: Something must have broken when you wrote your question because your code should not work at all with Bash, e.g. `for val in '/path/test_mail.txt'; do { stat path/$val | grep 'Modify: ' | cut -d' ' -f2,3,4 | awk -F"." '{print $1}' ; } | $val done` just cannot work unless `$val` is a command, which is probably not the case.

Comment: yes, it isnt working @vdavid , But i have explored so much regarding stat or ls taking the variable path, it is the main problem, really hope you can guide me the appropraite way

Comment: @Bodo well, in short, i am trying to find the duplicate files ( which have been downloaded from FTP site, it is another script file) and email the business  about all the duplicate files and its corresponding modified dates.

Comment: @Alekhyavarma Please answer all questions from my comment. What is the criteria to find duplicate files? What is `/path/test_mail.txt` or what do you want to do with this file? (If you want to read it, your script is wrong.)

Comment: I have made the changes @Bodo , please check

Comment: @Alekhyavarma I edited your question to show how I understood. Please check my change. To me it is still not yet clear. Do you only want to print output lines like "Duplicate Filename - abc.xlsx Uploaded time - 2020-02-17 11:18:10" for every file from `/path/test_mail.txt` with the file modification time? Is the file `/path/test_mail.txt` already a list of duplicates found by some other script?

Comment: you perfectly understood me! thats exactly what i am looking for @Bodo. yes, /path/test_mail.txt  belongs from another script which I have also mentioned right at the bottom of the question as optional, you can check that code too.. thank you

Comment: Find out what your `mail` command is. For example if it is Berkeley mailx or snail, (the latter a fork of the former) both provide the `-a` option to append a file to the email. If you have that option, why not simply write a temporary file and then append the file containing the modified information?

Answer (score 3):

I assume the file `/path/test_mail.txt` has been prepared by some other script (as a list of duplicate files) and the task is to add the modification time of the files listed in `/path/test_mail.txt` and format the output as shown in the question.

```
while IFS= read -r filename; do
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename") 
   printf 'Duplicate Filename - %s Uploaded time - %s\n' "$filename" "$mtime"
done < "/path/test_mail.txt"
```

Instead of parsing the file `/path/test_mail.txt` you could also add this to a pipe like this

```
somehow_print_duplicate_file_names | while IFS= read -r filename; do
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename") 
   printf 'Duplicate Filename - %s Uploaded time - %s\n' "$filename" "$mtime"
done | somehow_send_mail
```

You could add some error handling in case `stat` fails.

```
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename" 2>/dev/null || echo "unknown (stat failed)")
```

or use `stat`'s error message

```
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/path/$filename" 2>&1)
```

Comment: thank you for your response @Bodo

It says the following error 



./tj_mail1.ksh: line 2: path: command not found
./tj_mail1.ksh: line 3: filename: command not found
./tj_mail1.ksh: line 7: /path/test_mail.txt: No such file or directory



i've tried to give the path with single quotation, double quoatations and without them  path = '/filepath'  but none seems working

Comment: @Alekhyavarma `/path/test_mail.txt: No such file or directory` Apparently the file  `/path/test_mail.txt` does not exist. Use the real path of your file, check if it exists at this location. If you get error message and don't know how to debug or fix them, please copy&paste your **unmodified** script and the unmodified output including all error messages to the question.

Comment: @Bobo But i have tried your second piping option. it says path: command not found.. checked the real path, it is the same.. i wonder why it is assuming it as a command!

Comment: Added my actual script and error as well, please check

Comment: it is working when i removed the path variable and assigned it directly! thank you so much @Bodo

Comment: hey @Bodo can you also help me a little in the small piece of code above mentioned under the 'Little more!! section in the question. i'd really appreciate that

Comment: @Alekhyavarma Good that you fond the problem. If I understood correct, this apparently resulted from modifying your script for the question and using the example file or directory names in my answer unmodified. For the next time you should either not replace the file or directory names in your script with example names or create a testing environment on your system where you can run the script exactly as shown in the question.

Comment: @Alekhyavarma For the code below "Little more": Write a separate question. Add all important information. What actually happens when, what do you want to happen? What exactly means "duplicate file"? Same file name? Same file contents? Instead of writing technical things about your possibly wrong implementation like "...then perform the if condition and perform 'mv' command...", describe what should happen from the user's point of view, e.g. "all files `*.xlsx` and `*.csv` from directory `<source directory name>` shall be moved to "<destination directory>` and the output shall be empty".

Comment: ... What do you mean with "pipe the duplicate"? Print the file names? With or without directory? If there are 2 or 3 files considered duplicates of each other, do you want all the file names or all except the first one? ... Please explain all details in a new question.

Comment: @ Bodo , Hello , i have posted a new question, please check it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60508594/bash-script-to-find-the-duplicate-filenames-in-the-same-directory-and-send-a-not