# Bash Script to find the Duplicate filenames in the same directory and send a Notification email

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My aim is to find for any duplicates file names by comparing all the file names(abc.xyz , def.csv) in the same Directory. if there aren't any duplicate file names then move all those files(.csv , .xlsx) in the mentioned file path into Archive path.

If there are duplicate filenames, then fetch the names of those duplicate filenames only with their modified date timestamp and send a notification email to the team and move the remaining non-duplicate filenames to the archive folder.

As you can see I am trying to achieve it by the following code.

if the find command is empty, then perform the if condition and perform 'mv' command and exit the script entirely, if they are duplicate files, then exit the if condition and pipe the duplicate files and perform the mail and date stamp operation.

However the code what actually doing is, sending a notification email if it finds or does not find any duplicate files.

if there are duplicate files, then send an email with duplicate filenames and modification name , if there is no duplicate filnames, then it is sending the filename as blank and current time as modified time.

currently there are no files outside archive(only files inside archive, but all the files inside the archive are unique and looks good) so technically it shouldn't send any notification email.

[image: sourcefolder]

[image: data source inside archive]

```
{
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
dirname=/marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation
tempfile=myTempfileName
find $dirname -type f  > $tempfile
cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d|
while read fileName
do
 grep "$fileName" $tempfile
done
}
if ["$fileName" == ""]; then
         mv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/*.xlsx /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/Archive

         mv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/*.csv /marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/Archive
        exit 1

fi | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_var.txt' | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'  | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_var.txt' | sort -u | tee '/marketsource/scripts/tj_mail.txt'



DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
printf "%s\n" "$(</marketsource/scripts/tj_mail.txt)" | while IFS= read -r filename; do
   mtime=$(stat -c %y "/marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation/$filename")
   printf  'Duplicate Filename - %s Uploaded time - %s\n\n' "$filename" "$mtime"
done | mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" ti@gmail.com
```

Comment: Hello @Bodo Please find my question above.

Comment: It just isn't possible to have two files with the same name in the same directory.

Comment: @Alekhyavarma Your question is not clear. If the script does not do what you want, please describe exactly what should happen and what happens instead. If the problem is not related to the pipe  I suggest to remove the pipe with the loop to get the modification times and the mail sending. Show an example which files and subdirectories exist in `/marketsource/SrcFiles/Target_Shellscript_Autodownload/Airtime_Activation` To do this you can show (parts of) the contents of `myTempfileName`

Comment: Please find my changes and screenshot @Bodo

Comment: Paste your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it tells you. There are also a few fundamentals misconceptions around how pipes work, I believe.

Comment: @Benjamin Thank you for your response, sure ill check that. So, i hope my question and code looks understandable to you. Hope i am going through the correct path.

Comment: `(abc.xyz , def.csv)` `(.csv , .xlsx)` - so which extensions? `xyz` and `csv` or `csv` and `xlsx` or any extension? So you want to find duplicate filenames without extensions in a directory? `find . -mindepth 1 | sed 's/\..*//' | sort | uniq -d`? Right side of `|` is executed in a subshell - `fileName` is set inside `while` and will be unset in `if`.

Comment: sorry my bad.. its  .xlsx and .csv extensions

Comment: To me, it's still not clear what you're asking. You don't describe what exactly you expect to happen and what actually happens; and you should shorten your script as much as possible while preserving the relevant behaviour (see [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

> find for any duplicates file names by comparing all the file names(abc.xyz , def.csv) in the same Directory.
>
> its .xlsx and .csv extensions

I'm assuming there are no whitespaces in filenames

```
IFS=$'\n'

duplicates=($(
       find . -maxdepth 1 -type f '(' -name '*.xlsx' -o -name '*.csv' ')' \
           -exec bash -c 'printf "%s %s\n" "$1" "${1%.*}"' -- {} \; |
       sort -k1 |
       uniq -f1 -d |
       cut -d' ' -f2
))
# or simpler:
duplicates=($(
    find . -type f '(' -name '*.xlsx' -o -name '*.csv' ')' |
    sed 's/\.[^\.]*$//' |
    sort |
    uniq -d
))

IFS=$' \t\n'
```

> # if there aren't any duplicate file names then move all those files(.csv , .xlsx) in the mentioned file path into Archive path

```
if ((${#duplicates[@]} == 0)); then
    find . -type f '(' -name '*.xlsx' -o -name '*.csv' ')' \
         -exec mv -v {} "$the_archive_path" \;
```

> # If there are duplicate filenames, then

```
else
```

> # fetch the names of those duplicate filenames only with their modified date timestamp

```
    duplicate_filenames_with_modified_date=$(
       {
          printf "%s.xlsx\n" "${duplicates[@]}"
          printf "%s.csv\n" "${duplicates[@]}"
       } |
       xargs -d$'\n' stat -c '%n %y\n'
    )
```

> # and send a notification email to the team and

```
    mail the_team <<<"a notification email"
```

> # move the remaining non-duplicate filenames to the archive folder.

```
    find . -maxdepth 1 -type f '(' -name '*.xlsx' -o -name '*.csv' ')' \
           -exec bash -c 'echo "$1" "${1%.*}"' -- {} \; | tee /dev/stderr |
       sort -k2 |
       uniq -f1 -u |
       cut -d' ' -f1 |
       xargs -r -d$'\n' -I{} echo mv -v {} "$the_archive_folder"
fi
```

Comment: Using newline-delimited streams to contain lists of filenames is generally unsafe -- as you well know.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your response. So i have a created a dummy filename outside archive and excuted the script, it is doing nothing nor it send me any notification email . Can you please check .
I have modified the mail part

  duplicate_filenames_with_modified_date=$(
       {
          printf "%s.xlsx\n" "${duplicates[@]}"
          printf "%s.csv\n" "${duplicates[@]}"
       } |
       xargs -d$'\n' stat -c '%n %y\n'
    ) | mail -s "Duplicate file found ${DATE}" tli@aloup.com

Comment: You can't do `a=$(cmd1) | cmd2`. Variable assignment with [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) doesn't output anything, so redirecting it with `|` pipe will result that the second command receives empty input. Either remove assignment and substitution, or really just use the resulting variable. For email writing I would just use a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: Hello @kamilcuk, I referring to your script. i have executed your script and nothing seems to happen, regarding email yes, I will check that. thank you